# Where is the return value from "webdriver.Firefox" documented ? (Selenium / Webdriver)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

In the Selenium webdriver doco an example script, "Example 2", is provided https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/py#example-2

In the example the `title` property of the returned object, `self.browser`, is seen being used.

Where can I find documented what other properties that object has ?

Thanks

---

**EDIT**: Just to make a bit clearer what I'm after. I presume that the ...

```
self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

... `self.browser` provides access to a representation of the DOM of the current page. How do you gain access to that represenation ?

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver

Comment: Thanks but I can't see how that explains how the property 'title' comes about and how other parts of the DOM might be exposed through that object.

Comment: They are inherited: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver

Comment: Like @Sraw said, it's inherited from RemoteWebdriver. Maybe take a look to the souce code https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#L35 and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#L188 will give you more understanding.

Comment: @Sraw : Thanks that's what I was after, sorry for being obtuse.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra : Thanks that's what I was after too !